# NetSuite PHP Toolkit Sorting

Tags: php, netsuite, toolkit

I'm using the NetSuite PHP Toolkit and running a CustomerBasicSearch which works. However, I want to set an explicit sort on a column in the search. Is this possible with a basic or advanced search? If so how?

Comment: Where'd you get with this ?

Comment: There does not appear to be an explicit sorting. It does appear to sort by your first search criteria in ascending order. For example, if you search where internalid noneof 0, it will return all results ordered by internalid ascending.

Comment: sound great, ill try it

Comment: i tried this and it did not work for me, after all the order which you assign object properties does is not retained in any way: (how i started my search)

    $search = new TransactionSearchBasic();
    
    $SearchLongField = new SearchLongField();
    $SearchLongField->searchValue = 0;
    $SearchLongField->operator = "notEqualTo";

    $search->internalIdNumber = $SearchLongField;